# Get browserify require paths to behave more like requirejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, commonjs, browserify

I'm finding that it's a pain when moving files around and constantly having to rewrite the file include paths to be relative to their new folder.

I want to avoid this in my browserify code:

```js
var View = require('../../../../base/view');
```

And do something more in line with requirejs where it knows my base path is `js`:

```js
var View = require('base/view');
```

Comment: In [browserify doc](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#var-b--browserifyfiles-or-opts) there is an option called `opts.basedir` that I understand is doing what you are looking for:
`opts.basedir is the directory that browserify starts bundling from for filenames that start with .`

BUT, I cannot to get it to work myself (with `gulp-browserify`)

Comment: @8y5 it's for the first js file finally right? Not the whole js tree. So it doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: @SebastienLorber indeed `basedir` doesn't resolve the problem. `opts.paths` is what @Abadaba is looking for. I answered my own question with more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434494/browserify-basedir-option/22601755#22601755

Answer (score 13):

You should use the `paths` option. It is not documented in browserify but in [node-browser-resolve](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-browser-resolve) (used under the hood):

> paths - require.paths array to use if nothing is found on the normal
>   node_modules recursive walk

Comment: and How to do it:
https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/30/cleaning-up-browserifys-require-problem/

Answer (score 9):

A great option here is to use the `aliasify` plugin, available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aliasify).  Then just add something like this to your `package.json`, with all paths in the aliasify config being relative to the position of that file:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "aliasify"
    ]
  },
  "aliasify": {
    "aliases": {
      "app": "./src/app",
      "components": "./src/components",
      "someAlias": "./src/app/some/path/to/a/place",
      "foobar": "./go/to/a/module/named/foobar",
    }
  }
```

Then, in your files, just do:

```
var foobar = require("foobar");
var sampleComponent = require("components/someSample");

//My JS code
```

Answer (score 4):

## `node_modules`

You can put your application code (or a symlink to it, if your platform supports it) under `node_modules`. E.g.:

```
node_modules/
+-- app/
    +-- js/
        +-- base/
            +-- view.js
        +-- a/
            +-- b/
                +-- c/
                    +-- somefile.js
```

```js
// somefile.js                
require("app/js/base/view");
```

**However**, there's an important caveat: this breaks application of transforms specified programmatically via the API, e.g:

```
browserify('app/entry.js')
  .transform(es6ify)
```

In browserify there's a concept of "top-level" files that comes into play with transforms. That concept, and the behavior of transforms in general, is poorly explained in the browserify documentation. You can see some discussion of the issue here: [substack/node-browserify#993](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/993)

## pathmodify

Another option is my [pathmodify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathmodify) browserify plugin. This allows using non-relative paths and programmatic transforms. To enable browserifying code like:

```js
var View = require('base/view');
```

You would do something like:

```js
var pathmodify = require('pathmodify');

var opts = {mods: [
  // Maps require() IDs beginning with "base/" to begin with
  // "/somedir/js/base/"
  pathmodify.mod.dir("base", "/somedir/js/base"),
]};

// Give browserify the real path to entry file(s).
// pathmodify will transform paths in require() calls.
browserify('./js/entry')
  .plugin(pathmodify, opts)
  .transform(es6ify)
  .bundle()
  ...
```

## Combined

Note that pathmodify will only solve the problem for browserify. If you need the paths like `base/view` to also work in another context, like node, then if you have symlinks available you can combine the two. For example, symlink `node_modules/base` to `/somedir/js/base`, and also configure pathmodify as indicated and continue to point browserify to paths outside of `node_modules` for entry files.