# Browserify basedir option (RequireJS-like)

Tags: browserify, gulp

I cannot figure out how the [browserify `basedir` option](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#var-b--browserifyfiles-or-opts) works..

*Note*: I may be wrong in my understanding of the whole `basedir` concept because I'm coming from RequireJS (think `baseUrl`).

**EDIT**
Indeed I was wrong, but you can still achieve what I was trying to do with the `paths` option, see my answer below.

I understand that the `basedir` option gives you the ability (the freedom!) to specify all require paths (starting with a `.`) from a static root/base dir.. And NOT from `process.cwd()`..

This is literally driving me crazy, I though such a feature would be so basic to implement and that a lot of people would have run into the same issue as me, but there is actually very few info on the web about how to setup properly the `basedir` option.. And trust me, this is not straight-forward..

So here is the BASIC example that's driving me crazy.

Given the following file structure:

```
js/
js/app.js
js/src/models/Person.js
js/src/views/PersonView.js
```

And running:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {

  var b = browserify('./app', {basedir: './js'});

  b.bundle().pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

I would expect being able to do the following `require()` call in `PersonView.js`:

```
var Person = require('./src/models/Person');
...
```

Instead of (which is obviously working...):

```
var Person = require('../models/Person');
...
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: module "./src/models/Person" not found from "/Users/...some path.../js/src/views/PersonView.js"
```

What am I missing about the `basedir` option?

Comment: From the documentation, it sounds like `basedir` only affects the path(s) that you pass to `browserify` to initiate the bundling process (in your case, the path to `app.js`). The paths you use in `require()` will still be relative to the files they occur in.

Comment: Yep, thx, this is what I ended up understanding. The `paths` option of `browser-resolve` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that `basedir` is not the same as RequireJS's `baseUrl`. As stated by @Ben in the comment above, the official docs says:

> `opts.basedir` is the directory that browserify **starts bundling
>   from** for filenames that start with `.`.

[(source)](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#var-b--browserifyfiles-or-opts)

Meaning that `basedir` only applies to the [`entry` files](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#var-b--browserifyfiles-or-opts). Further `require` calls deep in the file tree structure will always be resolved relatively to the file currently being parsed.

### Answer to my question

The `paths` option of `browser-resolve` (which is used by `browserify` under the hood) is what I was looking for:

> paths - require.paths array to use if nothing is found on the normal
>   node_modules recursive walk

[(source)](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-browser-resolve)

Just pass this option along with other `browserify` options [when instantiating the bundler](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#var-b--browserifyfiles-or-opts).

*Note*: It looks like it is [messing up things](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/700#issuecomment-38139607) when using together with [`browserify-shim` transform](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim).

Comment: It may interest you to look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23608416/82609