# Set custom paths to files in Browserify

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browserify

I'm taking a crack at changing my current RequireJS workflow to a Browserify + Watchify one, solely for my frontend Javascript (my backend is Ruby).  The only issue I'm running into is that I don't have an easy place to configure what I would called "named paths".  Let's assume my frontend is structured like so:

```
app/
  models/
    ExampleModel.js
  views/
    ExampleView.js
  main.js
util/
  backbone-all.js
vendor/
  jquery-2.1.0.js
  backbone-1.1.2.js
  backbone-marionette-2.0.1.js
  underscore-1.6.0.js
```

In the example above, please note two things:

1. All of my vendored JS files have their version right in their filename
2. Note the `backbone-all.js` file in the `util` folder

With RequirejS, I could do something like the following:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery-2.1.0",
        "backbone": "vendor/backbone-1.1.2",
        "underscore": "vendor/underscore-1.6.0",
        "backbone-all": "util/backbone-all"
    }
});
```

And be able to require my code simply by name, rather than fully qualified (or even relative) path. I haven't yet been able to figure out a way to get this to work the exact way that I want on the frontend.  The closest I got was to create a dependency map file that is loaded before my application starts (and is globally available), and use it as the keys:

```
window.d = window.dependency = {
    "jquery": "/vendor/jquery-2.1.0",
    "backbone": "/vendor/backbone-1.1.2",
    "underscore": "/vendor/underscore-1.6.0",
    "backbone-all": "/util/backbone-all"
};

var $ = require(d.jquery);
```

Has anyone encountered this issue, or come across a suitable solution?  I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051663/get-browserify-require-paths-to-behave-more-like-requirejs) which is similar, but has no accepted answer from 6 months ago.  Perhaps things have changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `browser` field in your `package.json` to configure a map similar to requireJS's `paths` map. See [the browserify docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browser-field).

```
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./vendor/jquery-1.42.js",
  "./lib/ops.js": "./browser/opts.js"
}
```