# How to import without using relative location

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

In VS15, using aspnetcore RC2, this import statement works:

`import {DataService} from "./data-service";`

This does not:

`import {DataService} from "wwwroot/src/to-do/data-service";`

How can I import without using the relative path?  The reason for this is that I find I need to move files around during refactoring, and the relative path breaks.  So I prefer to use the full path.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something that you can do. You can achieve something not to far from that using [browerify or requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051663/get-browserify-require-paths-to-behave-more-like-requirejs). But the main problem that you are having is a design problem. I would recommend you to fix that instead.

You modules are coupled, that's why you change a a file to a different path you have to fix many other modules. You can solve this using the Dependency Inversion principle and an IoC container.

This problem and its solution are better explained in the following link:

> [The current state of dependency inversion in JavaScript](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/the-current-state-of-dependency-inversion-in-javascript#myth-2-we-don39t-need-ioc-containers-we-alrea_2)

If you are working with angular 2 you can use [its DI library](https://github.com/angular/di.js/). If you are working on a custom app or node.js you could use [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS).

Comment: I don't know that it is true that you cannot do that.  I have done it in early projects with typescript. Possibly something changed, but it seems to me it ought to work.